# Use calloutAccessoryControlTapped: method to load specific Viewcontroller

Tags: ios, annotations, uipopovercontroller, viewcontroller

I have a number of viewcontrollers that each hold their own content.  I want to load each viewController's content into their own popover that pops up when someone taps an annotation.  Since each annotation is a different location I want the popover that is attached to a particular annotation to load a specific viewController to show the detailed information about that annotation.

I currently have my popover code sitting inside my calloutAccessoryControlTapped: method.  I understand that this method should allow my code to somehow gain knowledge of which annotation was tapped. With this knowledge I could then set up some logic such as with IF statements or whatever so that I could load the popover and the corresponding viewcontroller that I want.

How can I pass the annotation that has been tapped into my code using the calloutAccessoryControlTapped: method?

Thanks,

Here is my code for loading ONE viewController.

// this is the method for recognizing when the DetailDisclosureButton is tapped.
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control

{

```
            // create an instance of the DetailViewController class that holds the additional info and initialize it
            DetailViewController *ycvc = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];



            // create an instance of the IUPopoverController class and initialize it with the instance created above
            UIPopoverController *poc = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:ycvc];
            [ycvc release];

            // hold the reference to the popover in an ivar
            self.popover = poc;

            //size the popover as needed
            poc.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 400);



            //show the popover next to the annotation view
            [poc presentPopoverFromRect:view.bounds inView:view
            permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];

            [poc release];
}
```